# What is the best approach for refreshing the page content/values after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, jsp, jakarta-ee

Please suggest some approach I have a device from which I am getting reading in the form of measurement like volt, amp, watt, etc so I have a dashboard.jsp page where I have to refresh the readings every 3 seconds and the device will be attached on network. So, threading is a good approach or ajax calls as some folks telling threading in a web applications make the loading slower and crash the application. I am confused please post your ideas and explain if possible.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way: add a meta tag in the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
```

This will reload the entire page every three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make ajax call on some interval.

```
setInterval(doAjaxCall, time); // time in MS

function doAjaxCall() {
    // ajax call logic
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.

Comment: If user need to refresh some part for page(i.e. in this case user need to update reading/measurement on page) then ajax call is useful rather to refresh whole page again.

Comment: I have modbus configuration wherein i am getting device measurements and after 3 seconds i have to update the values not the whole page. So, threading is not a good practice it seems, does it put extra load on the page ???